# How to concatenate strings from two different list index wise in commutative way

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I have two lists of strings and I want to concatenate them index wise in commutative way(AB = BA). I was able to get the output but I need some optimal way to do it.
Two lists are:

```
bus0 = ['NEVP', 'IPCO']
bus1 = ['CISO', 'DUK']
```

**Expected output:**

```
all links:  ['NEVP-CISO', 'IPCO-DUK', 'CISO-NEVP', 'DUK-IPCO']
```

The way I did it some thing like this

```
link1 = ['-'.join([i, j ]) for i, j in zip(bus0, bus1)]
link2 = ['-'.join([j, i]) for i, j in zip(bus0, bus1)]
allPossibleLinks = link1 + link2
print('link1: ', link1)
print('link2: ', link2)
print('all links: ', allPossibleLinks)
```

As you can see I use two for loops, so I want to is there a method to do this in one loop or any other better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in one loop, just not a list comprehension (technically you can, it would just get ugly).

```
bus0 = ['NEVP', 'IPCO']
bus1 = ['CISO', 'DUK']

all_links = []
for i, j in zip(bus0, bus1):
    all_links.append(f'{i}-{j}')
    all_links.append(f'{j}-{i}')
```

Comment: Hey, thank you man

Answer (score 1):

the answer is asked in this order
`['NEVP-CISO', 'IPCO-DUK', 'CISO-NEVP', 'DUK-IPCO']`
not
`['NEVP-CISO', 'CISO-NEVP', 'IPCO-DUK', 'DUK-IPCO']`

```
all_links = []
temp = []
for (i,j) in zip(bus0, bus1):
    all_links.append(i + '-' + j)
    temp.append(j + '-' + i)
all_links.extend(temp)
print(all_links)
```

Output now looks like -
`['NEVP-CISO', 'IPCO-DUK', 'CISO-NEVP', 'DUK-IPCO']`